# Check value from localStorage but showing undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyauyg0k/3/)

I have adding the value in the following structure `localStorage.COMMENT_DESCRIPTION.list_no` but its always showing undefined.

But when I print into the console.log it shows the data. The problem is when I'm checking with condition it is not working

```
var comment_description = {};
$("#add_list_img").click(function()
{
    if(localStorage.COMMENT_DESCRIPTION)
    {
        alert(localStorage.COMMENT_DESCRIPTION.list_no);  # Here is the problem. I have added the value but the variable is empty
        if(localStorage.COMMENT_DESCRIPTION.list_no == undefined)
        {
            alert("Here so");
            cart_val =  localStorage.COMMENT_DESCRIPTION.list_no || 1;
            comment_description.list_no = cart_val+1;
            console.log(comment_description);
            storage();
        }
        else
        {   
            alert("here");          

            cart_val = comment_description.list_no;
            comment_description.list_no = cart_val+1;
            storage();
        }   
    }
    else
    {

        cart_val = 1;
        comment_description.list_no = cart_val+1;
        storage();
    }

});

function storage()
{
    if(localStorage.COMMENT_DESCRIPTION)
    {
        var oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('COMMENT_DESCRIPTION'));
        console.log("strogae "+comment_description.list_no);
        var newItems = $.extend({}, oldItems, comment_description);
        localStorage.setItem('COMMENT_DESCRIPTION',JSON.stringify(newItems));

    }
    else
    {   
        var lc_no = {"list_no":1,"card_no":1};
        var newItems = $.extend({},comment_description);
        localStorage.setItem('COMMENT_DESCRIPTION',JSON.stringify(newItems));
    }

        console.log("added following"+localStorage.COMMENT_DESCRIPTION);
}
```

Comment: `localStorage.COMMENT_DESCRIPTION` is a JSON string. You need to parse it first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse it first

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.COMMENT_DESCRIPTION).list_no
```

the content of your `localStorage.COMMENT_DESCRIPTION` is in JSON string not yet an object

revised working fiddle of yours

https://jsfiddle.net/cyauyg0k/3/